# Logic for conditional file delete in a unix script

Tags: unix

Scenario:

I have a unix script which generates a file with name `TARGET_FILE`.

I have to write a variable `runType` inside the file.

If for a given day, the script is running for the first time, then `runType` will be `NEWRUN` else it will have value `RERUN`.

To evaluate `runType` I have written the following logic:

```
#!/bin/ksh
# get the date from database
curr_dt=logic to get date from database

# create and echo the filename by joining the date
myFlagFileName=My_Flag_File_$curr_dt
echo $myFlagFileName

# check if the file exists
if [ -f $MY_DIR/$myFlagFileName ];
then
    # RERUN if exists
    runType=RERUN
else 
    # NEW if not exists and create the file
    runType=NEWRUN
    touch $MY_DIR/$myFlagFileName
fi 

# echo the evaluated runType
echo $runType
```

The script assigns `NEWRUN` to `runType` and generates a flag file with current date appended in the name and on rerun on the same date, it checks existence of the flag file and accordingly sets `runType` to `RERUN`.

I want to include proper logic in the above script to delete old flag files on next day's run.

How can I delete all the previous day's file ?

If say script does not run for several days, the flag file present will have a much older date. So I can not delete the flag file simply by using previous day's date.

I am looking for logic where given current date, it should delete all the file with appended dates in file name less than current date.

Comment: `rm $MY_DIR/My_Flag_File* >/dev/null 2>&1` before the line starting `touch...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Could you pls explain the command in an answer below so that I can accept it if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first run of the day, there should be exactly ONE flag file - the one for today. So, at that point you can safely remove all other flag files from any other days. The error messages are discarded to `/dev/null` if there are no old flag files to remove.

```
#!/bin/ksh
# get the date from database
curr_dt=logic to get date from database

# create and echo the filename by joining the date
myFlagFileName=My_Flag_File_$curr_dt
echo $myFlagFileName

# check if the file exists
if [ -f $MY_DIR/$myFlagFileName ];
then
   # RERUN if exists
   runType=RERUN
else 
   # NEW if not exists and create the file
   runType=NEWRUN
   rm $MY_DIR/My_Flag_File* >/dev/null 2>&1         # NEW CODE HERE
   touch $MY_DIR/$myFlagFileName
fi 

# echo the evaluated runType
echo $runType
```